# Basic SQL Script to find a special character, but only when present more than once

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am relearning MS-SQL for a project.

I have a table with a field where the data includes the special character `|`. 
Most times the field does not have it, sometimes once, sometimes 4 times.

I have been able to get it filtered to when present, but I would like to try to show only the times it appears more than once.

This is what I have come up so far:

```
SELECT  UID, OBJ_UID, DESCRIPTION
FROM SPECIFICS
WHERE (NAMED LIKE '%[|]%')
```

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `|` with blank and compare length of strings

```
SELECT 
    UID, OBJ_UID, DESCRIPTION 
FROM 
    SPECIFICS 
WHERE 
    LEN(NAMED) - LEN(REPLACE(NAMED, '|', '')) > 1
```

Query returns rows where `|` appears more than one time

Comment: That works great, and not as complicated like the answers I found searching. Thanks for the help.